# How can I choose or calculate the function $f(t)$ in $(a*t+b)/(c*f(t)+d)$ to best approximate a given linear function in the t=[0,1] interval?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, approximation

I have an expression with an unknown function $p(t)$

$$g(t)=(921600*(-1333.33340000000*t + 2000)/(-3.36000004800000e6*p(t) + 3840000)$$

I would like to calculate somehow the $p(t)$ function that the $g(t)$ function approximates best the following linear function in the $t=[0,1]$ interval:

$$f(t)=(1280-500)*t+500$$

For example if I choose $p(t)=sqrt(t)$, the blue curve, or $p(t)=pow(t,0.4594)$ for the black curve:

[image]

But how can I work out a better fitting function of $p(t)$  or perhaps finding the best one?

I think I should calculate some kind of series expansion to a certain order, and to measure somehow the area between the linear line and the calculated curve, to measure the goodness of the chosen function.

For my purposes it also would be useful when exchanging $t$ and $p(t)$ in the expression of $g(t)$, like:

$$g(t)=(921600*(-1333.33340000000*p(t) + 2000)/(-3.36000004800000e6*t + 3840000)$$

To find another $p(t)$ in the expression of $g(t)$ to approximate $f(t)$ again. Maybe in this form the problem would be easier.

Maybe even an exact solution could be found by integrating a differential equation:

$$g'(t)=f'(t)=1280-500$$

How can I work out all of these? I have only Sage Math as a symbolic computer algebra system.

Comment: Solving $(a t+b)/(c f(t)+d)=c_1+c_2 t $ for $f(t)$ we get $f(t) = ((a-c_2 d)t+b-c_1 d)/(c(c_1+c_2 t))$

Comment: In this case the solution was more simpler, than I thought. But kind of interesting: we divide a linear function with a nonlinear function, and we got back a linear function.

Comment: @Konstantin I get $p(t) = ((440 t + 8) / (273 t + 175))$, which is not a linear function.

Comment: Yes, exactly. What I meant, it was that I divide a linear numerator in the expression of g(t) with a denominator, which contains that non-linear p(t), thus the denominator is also a non-linear function. And what we got finally this way for g(t) becomes a linear function. I think for linear nominator the linearizing denominator should be always hiperbolic, like in this case. Generally: are there always a  non-trivial p(t) which transforms an arbitrary f(t) function by division - f(t)/p(t) - into a linear function?